# How to use 3 levels of quotes in .json object property?

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to set the following terminal command to the npm script `npm run test:unit` inside `package.json`:

```
node_modules/.bin/jest --watch --testPathIgnorePatterns=['Functional']
```

I need 2 levels of quotes for the `testPathIgnorePattern` argument. With the JSON property needing to enclose in "" to identify as a string, that makes 3 total.

My attempt below doesn't work. Does anyone know how to use 3 levels of quotes inside .json?

```
// package.json
"test:unit" : "node_modules/.bin/jest --watch --testPathIgnorePatterns='['Functional']'"
```

Comment: Escape the quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Escape the quotes:

```
"test:unit" : "node_modules/.bin/jest --watch --testPathIgnorePatterns=\"['Functional']\""
```